# How to make a vala application preffer dark GTK theme variant?

Tags: gtk, vala

I have a vala application and I would like it to use dark gtk theme instead of default light one.

Gtkparasite "Use dark variant" switch allows me to do that, but how can I do it programmatically?

Comment: @ptomato question you pointed out shows a solution in C not Vala. The way you access gtk application settings is different for each language.

Comment: Actually, it's quite the same no matter what language you access it from, due to the magic of GObject Introspection. I can tell you in Javascript as well: `Gtk.Settings.get_default().gtk_application_prefer_dark_theme = true;` but that doesn't mean we need a separate question for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I found a way. The following should be executed before any widget is created:

```
Gtk.Settings.get_default().set("gtk-application-prefer-dark-theme", true);
```